# Replace critical section with boost::detail::spinlock cause dead lock on windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost, mutex, spinlock

My platform is vs2010 win2003 server, I have an application working well. There is an integer protected by a critical section, when I modify and use boost::detail::spinlock instead then it goes to dead lock.

Comment: Soooo what did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: why the change was needed when it's working well ? BTW, is that the only change made ?

Comment: @DenisErmolin I use Interlockedxx api to solve it temporarily, but the true reason is still not found.

Comment: @Jagannath For what the critical section protects is only an integer, so I want to use spinlock to improve the performance. I'm sure it's the only change made, for I use mutex or Interlocked the dead lock disappered.

Comment: @magicyang: No, you want to use ATOMICs. Good news is that latest boost has them.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's `boost::detail::spinlock`. That means it's intended for internal use only. If you want portable replacement for critical sections, use [`boost::mutex` from Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.mutex).
2. It's `boost::detail::spinlock`. Spinlocks usually busy-wait, which makes them faster, but usable only under tightly controlled conditions.
3. Boost 1.53 (the latest release) finally got [Boost.Atomic](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/atomic.html), which is a portable (and C++11 compatible) replacement for interlocked operations.

Comment: If it's only for internal use, maybe it's collapse with the smart pointer or others. I'll try the latest boost, thank you.

Comment: @magicyang: Boost often reimplements bits of generic infrastructure in the `details` subnamespace to keep the components independent. But doing this it makes various complex assumptions that are only true about the boost code, which makes these bits unusable in your own code.